# Can you pass a Stateful Component a function to run inside componentDidMount()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

### Background

I am trying to pass a function called `execute()` via props to the `componentDidMount()` function inside of the `ChildComponent`. The function should execute in the context of `ChildComponent` and not within the context of `App`. For example, I want to be able to call `this.props` from inside the `() => {}` of the `execute` prop, but `this.props` refers to the props of `ChildComponent` and not `App`.

Is this possible?

### Example

`App.js`:

```js
import React from 'react';

import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent';

const App = () => (
    <>
      <ChildComponent
          execute={() => {console.log('Hello, World.');}}
      />
    </>
);

export default App;
```

`ChildComponent.js`:

```js
import React from 'react';

class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.execute();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <h1>Hello, World.</h1>
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default ChildComponent;
```

Comment: You can send the props in the `execute` params

Comment: It's only possible if you pass the App props in when passing it down to the child component, e.g. `<ChildComponent execute={() => console.log(this.props) />`

Comment: @Jayce444 what if I wanted to call setState from within the `execute` prop?

Comment: After the edit you just made, that new code should work.

Comment: If you want to use the props, you already have access at the `App` level, since that is where you pass them down. If you want to use `setState` then this would couple the two components, as the `App` component would need to know how the `ChildComponent` state is set.

Comment: @NicholasAdamou then you need to pass `setState`, or a function which calls `setState`, down as a prop to the child component

Comment: Please post what exactly you need to achieve as lifting the state to the `App` and passing what you want down to the `ChildComponent` as props seems a better approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This violates the [react unidirectional data flow principle](https://flaviocopes.com/react-unidirectional-data-flow/), but you can solve it this way:

```
import React from 'react';

class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        return this.props.length > 0 ? this.props.execute.bind(this)() : '';
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <h1>Hello, World.</h1>
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default ChildComponent;
```

In the parent component, you will have to change the arrow function to the ordinary function syntax:

```
import React from 'react';

import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent';

const App = () => (
    <>
      <ChildComponent
          execute={function() {console.log(this.props);}}
      />
    </>
);

export default App;
```

Now, inside the `execute` scope, `this` will refer to the `ChildComponent` instance, so inside the `execute function` you will be able to access `this.props` like you would inside the `ChildComponent`. Hope it helps you.

Comment: nope you will not be able to access it because the `execute` is an arrow function and it is already bound to the `this` of the `App` component. They will have to use a normal `function(){...}` to do this.

Comment: yeah sure, you will have to use `function` syntax